# jQuery works offline but doesn't work online

Tags: jquery

I made a page with two different jQuery effects, one works fine but the background effect doesn't work only in online mode. Offline works...

Firebug shows two errors:

> ReferenceError: b2AABB is not defined
>
> worldAABB = new b2AABB(); (Zeile 58, Spalte 1)

and

> SyntaxError: illegal character
>
> ï»¿
>
> Main.js (Zeile 58, Spalte 1)

This part od the code looks like this:

```
function init() {

  canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );

  document.onmousedown = onDocumentMouseDown;
  document.onmouseup = onDocumentMouseUp;
  document.onmousemove = onDocumentMouseMove;
  document.ondblclick = onDocumentDoubleClick;

  document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
  document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
  document.addEventListener( 'touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd, false );

  // init box2d

  worldAABB = new b2AABB(); // this is the line 58
  worldAABB.minVertex.Set( -200, -200 );
  worldAABB.maxVertex.Set( screen.width + 200, screen.height + 200 );

  world = new b2World( worldAABB, new b2Vec2( 0, 0 ), true );

  setWalls();
  reset();
}
```

The `ajax.googleapis` is local in the FTP.

Comment: The illegal character looks like a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Where is `b2AABB` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You use $(document).ready() to call init function?

If the js file is not loaded before you call the function the call fails.